# Twitter + oAuth nightmare

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to implement a custom login view to Twitter (I don't want that UIWebView).
I've downloaded many classes, and I'm so far having a *nightmare* with this. Now I'm trying to make Twitter + oAuth work. Here's the demo code (that works):

```
_engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
_engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
_engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

[_engine requestRequestToken];

UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

if (controller) 
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
else
    [_engine sendUpdate: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already Updated. %@", [NSDate date]]];
```

Now what I wanna do is replace that SA_OAuthTwitterController with custom UITextFields. So I'm trying this:

```
_engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
_engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
_engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

[_engine requestRequestToken];
[_engine requestAccessToken];
[_engine setUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
[_engine sendUpdate:@"tweet"];
```

But I keep getting error 401. I'm probably missing a step. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bit you're missing is here, SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m:103:

```
    //This generates a URL request that can be passed to a UIWebView. It will open a page in which the user must enter their Twitter creds to validate
- (NSURLRequest *) authorizeURLRequest {
        if (!_requestToken.key && _requestToken.secret) return nil;     // we need a valid request token to generate the URL

        OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: self.authorizeURL consumer: nil token: _requestToken realm: nil signatureProvider: nil] autorelease];     

        [request setParameters: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [[[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName: @"oauth_token" value: _requestToken.key] autorelease]]];   
        return request;
}
```

You will have to "fake" this user login out yourself, I believe by sending twitter the login credentials as a separate request. It appears that the setUsername method you're calling is actually called as a post operation once a valid access token has been received. See SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m:185

```
//
// access token callback
// when twitter sends us an access token this callback will fire
// we store it in our ivar as well as writing it to the keychain
// 
- (void) setAccessToken: (OAServiceTicket *) ticket withData: (NSData *) data {
        if (!ticket.didSucceed || !data) return;

        NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        if (!dataString) return;

        if (self.pin.length && [dataString rangeOfString: @"oauth_verifier"].location == NSNotFound) dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingFormat: @"&oauth_verifier=%@", self.pin];

        NSString                                *username = [self extractUsernameFromHTTPBody:dataString];

        if (username.length > 0) {
                [[self class] setUsername: username password: nil];
                if ([_delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(storeCachedTwitterOAuthData:forUsername:)]) [(id) _delegate storeCachedTwitterOAuthData: dataString forUsername: username];
        }

        [_accessToken release];
        _accessToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:dataString];
}
```

So the steps are as follows:

1. Request request token
2. Fake user login to twitter and get the pin value
3. Set the pin on the engine
4. Request access token

You can see where SA_OAuthTwitterController parses the pin out of the webview content in SA_OAuthTwitterController.m:156

```
#pragma mark Webview Delegate stuff
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) webView {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"jQueryInject" ofType: @"txt"];
    NSString *dataSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (dataSource == nil) {
        NSLog(@"An error occured while processing the jQueryInject file");
    }

        [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:dataSource]; //This line injects the jQuery to make it look better

        NSString                                        *authPin = [[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('oauth_pin').innerHTML"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if (authPin.length == 0) authPin = [[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('oauth_pin').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        if (authPin.length) {
                [self gotPin: authPin];
        } 
        if ([_webView isLoading] || authPin.length) {
                [_webView setHidden:YES];
        } else {
                [_webView setHidden:NO];
        }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for awesome answer. However I ended up using the UIWebView. I thought most apps were doing using oAuth on those UITextFields, but they're not. Hence the "posted via API".

Answer (score 2):

The view controller you are eliminating loads a webview that prompts the user to authenticate your application with twitter. If you don't ever have the user authenticate, you won't be able to make authenticated twitter calls. There is a way to do what you are wanting, however, you have to go through all of the OAuth steps yourself. Here are the steps as specified from a [different web service (Vimeo)](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/oauth), but the same rules apply:

> 1. Your application sends a request
>      with your consumer key, and signed
>      with your consumer secret, for a
>      something called a request token. If
>      we verify your application
>      correctly, we'll send you back a
>      request token and a token secret.
> 2. You'll then create a link for the user to click on with the request token.
> 3. When the user gets to Vimeo, they'll be prompted to allow your
>      application access to their account.
>      If they click yes, we'll send them
>      back to your application, along with
>      a verifier.
> 4. You'll then use the request token, verifier, and token secret to make
>      another call to us to get an access 
>      token. The access token is what 
>      you'll use to access the user's 
>      information on Vimeo.

OAuth is a real pain in the rump, so good luck. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [xAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) for custom user/pass controls. But it requires the permission from Twitter.